# How to insert a placeholder in a json key:value ? Flutter

Tags: flutter, localization

I'm porting my Swift app to Flutter and for localising it I'm following this https://github.com/billylev/flutter_localizations but I can't see how to insert placeholder to insert a value in the translated values. 
Basically the guide uses

```
String text(String key) {
    return _localisedValues[key] ?? "$key not found";
  }
```

to get the corresponding key:value pair from a .json file as

```
{
  "Shop": "Negozio",
}
```

I just pass it in the `Text`widget as :

`Text(AppLocalizations.instance.text('Shop'))`.

How to modify `text` to insert one or more placeholders and how would be the .json be constructed? 
Say for the value `"User": "User"` I'd like to insert a value after the transaction I can simply use a string sum and add the value as `Text(
                            AppLocalizations.instance.text('User') + ' ${widget.user.name}', but if I need to insert a value in the middle of the translated sentence, eg a message, I don't see how to accomplish it.
I need it to make localised versions of incoming push notification, and they have args.

In Swift I have it like this:

```
"ORDER_RECEIVED_PUSH_TITLE" = "Order number: %@";
"ORDER_RECEIVED_PUSH_SUBTITLE" = "Shop: %@";
"ORDER_RECEIVED_PUSH_BODY" = "Thank you %@! We received your order and we'll let you know when we start preparing it and when it's ready. Bye";
```

Any suggestions on how to accomplish that in Flutter?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was suggested this package https://pub.dev/packages/sprintf#-installing-tab- and it works just as I needed. Sprintf just lets you specify one or more placeholders in a String and pass an array of args.
https://developermemos.com/posts/using-sprintf-flutter-dart. for more info, even this is pretty much it. So for example

`"ORDER_RECEIVED_PUSH_TITLE" = "Order number: %@";`

in the .json file would be :

```
{
  "ORDER_RECEIVED_PUSH_TITLE": "Oder number: %s"
}
```

and using it would be

```
String orderNumber = 'some uuid';
Text(Sprintf(AppLocalitazions.instance.text('ORDER_RECEIVED_PUSH_TITLE'),[orderNumber]);
```

Hope this helps others.